# js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version (Openshift nodejs)

Tags: javascript, c++, ruby, node.js

I install my app one year ago and run fine. There is a "test" app after buy a dedicated server.

The last few months c'ant connect with external database (mongolab) because I recieve this message.

After investigate the log file, the problem may be my Ruby version, because I recive the error message "You have 1.8 and need 1.9.3 of ruby".

How can I update ruby package from openshitf nodejs server to versión 1.9.3 ?.

PD:In local nodejs instance, all run ok (I have ruby 1.9.3). Only when I send my app to the server i see this error.

I try update and install ruby but still equal, when i ask "ruby --version", only 1.8 version are instaled.

Any ideas to resolve this issue  ?.

Comment: In local nodejs instance, all run ok. Only when I send my app to the server i see this error.

Comment: Put that information as part of the question as well. Also clarify, what you mean by "more or less", did you mean the error message is not accurate or you are unable to know whether 1.9.3 is a lower version or a higher version than 1.8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days I found the problem.
My app has created two years ago. I think any module (may be socket.io) was a old release and (for any reason) do not update with "npm update".
I create a new app, copy all implementation and install the modules from blank app and ... all run fine whithout any changes.

Thanks for all.